# Convert/Export JSON to CSV

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

JSON file:

```
"UserDetailList": [
        {
            "UserName": "citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning", 
            "GroupList": [], 
            "CreateDate": "2017-11-07T14:20:14Z", 
            "UserId": "1234556", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
                }, 
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
                }
            ], 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning"
        }, 
        {
            "UserName": "rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions", 
            "GroupList": [], 
            "CreateDate": "2018-03-09T11:13:38Z", 
            "UserId": "AIDAJQOQGKISLCWDXG6EQ", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "IAMReadOnlyAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMReadOnlyAccess"
                }
            ], 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:user/rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions"
        }
    ]
```

with

```
jq -r '.UserDetailList[] | [.UserName] | @csv' output.json > fileout2.csv
```

I can get

```
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning"
"rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions"
```

How to get IAM policies for these 2 users, i need to extract AmazonEC2FullAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess under AttachedManagedPolicies ?

so output can be

```
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonEC2FullAccess
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonS3FullAccess
rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions,IAMReadOnlyAccess
```

Comment: Post your input JSON and post exact expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to extract .UserName as a variable before iterating over the inner array:

```
.UserDetailList[] 
| .UserName as $u
| .AttachedManagedPolicies[]
| [$u, .PolicyName]
| @csv
```

Of course this assumes valid JSON input.