# How to convert a JSON array to a CSV row?

Tags: json, bash, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I'm trying to convert a large `JSON` file to a `CSV` format. (I've just learned how to use `jq` so I'm still a beginner).

I've successfully managed to convert most of the data, however, I'm stuck at an array. Every `JSON` object in the file is supposed to be converted to a single `CSV` row, and I can't get that to work.

I've been trying to help myself with an existing answer:
[Convert/Export JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191968/convert-export-json-to-csv)

But the problem is that this method writes a row for each item in the array, needlessly repeating information.

I am using the same type of command as the above answer, the only difference being the name of the columns, but the array blocks...

For instance, I could have a `JSON` file resembling:

```
{resources:[
    {"id":"001","name"="Robert","items":[
        {"label":"00A","name":"Pen"},
        {"label":"00B","name":"Paper"}],
    {"id":"002","name"="Bruce","items":[
        {"label":"00A","name":"Pen"},
        {"label":"00B","name":"Computer"},
        {"label":"00C","name":"Headphones"}]
]
}
```

That I would like to become:

```
001,Robert,Pen,Paper,
002,Bruce,Pen,Computer,Headphones
```

I only need the `name` columns of the array

For the moment, the result is:

```
001,Robert,Pen
001,Robert,Paper
002,Bruce,Pen,
002,Bruce,Computer
002,Bruce,Headphones
```

The problem is the actual array is about 30 items long for each `JSON` object, making it impossible to use this way.

Comment: even if you simply adapted the code from another answer, could you include your current jq code ?

Comment: Here you have a posible solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163845/using-jq-to-extract-values-and-format-in-csv

Comment: Your JSON is not syntactically valid. Provide on that is in the right syntax - https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '.resources[] | [.id,.name,.items[].name] | @csv' < /tmp/b.json
"001","Robert","Pen","Paper"
"002","Bruce","Pen","Computer","Headphones"
```

Comment: olirwin - If you don't want the additional quotation marks even if that means the output is not a valid CSV representation of your data, you could replace the trailing `@csv` by `join(",")`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use awk to fix up your current output file.

```
awk -F, '{a[$1","$2]=a[$1","$2]","$3}; END{for (v in a) print v a[v]}' in.txt | sort >out.txt
```

Input:

```
001,Robert,Pen
001,Robert,Paper
002,Bruce,Pen,
002,Bruce,Computer
002,Bruce,Headphones
```

Output:

```
001,Robert,Pen,Paper
002,Bruce,Pen,Computer,Headphones
```